# What's the meaning of "Yo quería que nos pasara / y tú, y tú / lo dejaste pasar" in the song "Nada fue un error" by Coti?

Tags: expresiones, letras-de-canciones

In the song "Nada fue un error" Coti sings:

> Tengo una mala noticia
> No fue de casualidad
> Yo quería que nos pasara
> Y tú, y tú
> Lo dejaste pasar

What's the meaning of the verb **pasar** in the phrases **Yo quería que nos pasara** and **Y tú, y tú lo dejaste pasar**?

Does it have the same meaning in both phrases?

All I got searching online and using Google translator are literal translations (both in English and Portuguese - my native language) and I'm not sure if literal translations should be used here.

Comment: I always understood that it meant that he wanted that "something **happened** between them (and the other one let it happen)". I think that "pasar" is "algo pasara **entre nosotros**".

Comment: Y yo que pensaba que la canción era de Julieta Venegas... la de cosas que se aprenden aquí :)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' La primera vez que escuché de casualidad el disco de Coti "Tanta magia" fue un continuo "oohh, esta es de este pibe? Yo creí que era de los Enanitos Verdes/Julieta Venegas/Diego Torres/Enrique Iglesias/Paulina Rubio..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a clever play on words. *Pasar* means "to happen" and "to pass (by)". In this case, it means the former in one verse and the latter in the next.

- *Yo quería que nos pasara* = "I wanted it to happen to us" (what exactly should have happened it left implicit, but I assume it's finding love, a relationship, etc.).
- *Y tú, y tú / Lo dejaste pasar* = "And you (and you) let it pass by" (that is, you allowed it—the chance for something significant to happen—to pass by and be lost).

Of course the second verse could be interpreted differently, with *pasar* having the same meaning as in the first. That is, *Lo dejaste pasar* = "You let it happen". But the tone and theme of the song suggest to me this is isn't the idea.  When someone wants something good in love to happen and the other person lets it happen, then usually no song is written about it. Besides, it would be rather clumsy to use the same verb in this way if not for wordplay.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I'm just starting learning Spanish and getting this kind of support is really encouraging. And the cleverness of the phrase "When someone wants something good in love to happen and the other person lets it happen, then usually no song is written about it" really put a smile on my face. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

«Yo quería que nos pasara» could be saying that 'I would like that it will pass us.' Or, in more idiomatic English, 'I want this to pass us by.'

«Y tú, y tú lo dejaste pasar» could be saying that 'And you, and you let it pass.'

I think that others more familiar with the song and the subtleties of Spanish have more likely given you a better translation, but I'm reading literally that the singer wanted him and someone else to get over something, and the other person did get over it.